# Unable to resume activity on onActivityResult when ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent returns on landscape camera orientation

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, landscape

I searched a lot before writing the question. 
I have an Intent to pick an image from the camera with extra_output to store in the Uri

When the image is caught in portrait and / or without automatic rotation works perfectly.
However if you are in landscape and automatic rotation SOME models gives me error.

My Intent code:

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
startActivityForResult(camera, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

My onActivityResult fragment code:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ImageView imageFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageIncidenciaDetail);
    imatgeOriginal = null;

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //if(imageFile != null)
        imatgeOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

I actually have two different errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity     {com.vicopo.com.lapoblainfo/com.vicopo.com.lapoblainfo.incidencia_detail}:     java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.vicopo.com.lapoblainfo/com.vicopo.com.lapoblainfo.incidencia_detail}:    java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3865)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null,     request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity         {com.vicopo.com.lapoblainfo/com.vicopo.com.lapoblainfo.incidencia_detail}:             java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3488)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)
... 13 more 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.vicopo.com.lapoblainfo.incidencia_detail.onActivityResult(incidencia_detail.java:145)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5311)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3484)
... 14 more
```

And

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1,   result=-1, data=null} to activity     {com.vicopo.com.lapoblainfo/com.vicopo.com.lapoblainfo.incidencia_detail}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3178)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at   com.vicopo.com.lapoblainfo.incidencia_detail.onActivityResult(incidencia_detail.java:145)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3131)
... 11 more
```

And Android Manifest activity code:

```
<activity
        android:name=".incidencia_detail"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_incidencia_detail"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        >
```

I can do an if and and check that the image is not null. If I do that app not crash, but the image is null.

Comment: Your process may be terminated before control returns to you from the third-party camera app. How are you holding onto `imageFile`, such that it will not be `null` in that case?

Comment: When you say "the image is null", you mean `imatgeOriginal` or `imageFoto`?

Comment: When I say "the image is null" I mean imageFile

imageFile is a File that I pass to output_extra
imageFoto is an imageView. This never be null, by default I put an internal image
imageOriginal is a Bitmap. 
I convert File to a Bitmap when I receive from camera or Gallery


I saw my code again and I not have super.onActivityResult.That may be the problem?

Comment: I create `imageFile` in the onclick button.

Perhaps, if the system removes the activity, when returns it create a new activity, but the `imageFile` instance is null, because onclick is not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the `imageFile` path on the `saveInstanceState(Bundle out)` of your `Activity` and restore the `imageFile` at the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, if `savedInstanceState != null`. You may need to store the `imageFile` as a `String` in order to save it to the `Bundle`.